# SQL SERVER - Evitar cambios en la DB si falla la Query

Tags: sql-server

estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente con una query, es que dentro de la misma tiene varios UPDATES y varios INSERT... Si por alguna razón la query se me corta al medio por alguna excepción los primeros inserts/updates se hacen y los del final no, esto hace que se me genere conflicto en la base de datos porque se genera movimientos de un articulo pero por ejemplo cuando vas a ver el stock, este no sufrio cambios justamente por este error que se genera a mitad de la query..

Hay alguna manera de que si falla se reviertan los cambios?
O comprobar la query?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Haz tus operaciones en el marco de una transacción. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Siempre es deseable que incluyas en tu pregunta un ejemplo mínimo verificable de lo que intentas hacer. Será más fácil mostrarte cómo ajustar ese código para que haga lo que deseas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucion. usar Tran y RollBack

```
declare @Error as int
begin tran

****QUERYS****

set @Error = @@Error
if(@Error <> @Error)
begin 
ROLLBACK tran
end
```

Comment: Te faltó el commit

Answer (score 6):

Como ya lo han mencionado en las otras respuestas, lo que necesitas es usar transacciones explicitas. Las transacciones explícitas permitirán que varias operaciones se comporten como una sola y siempre se tenga que cumplir todo o fallar todo. Es parte de las propiedades ACID de las bases de datos.

Para manejar transacciones explícitas siempre es bueno manejar control de errores con TRY...CATCH para evitar dejar transacciones abiertas. El siguiente es un esqueleto que funciona para versiones 2012 en adelante.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION --Abrimos la transacción explicita

    --Incluimos nuestras operaciones DML
    UPDATE Tabla SET
        columna = valor
    WHERE condicion = 'true';

    INSERT INTO OtraTabla
    SELECT Muchas,
           Columnas
    FROM Origen;

    --Finalizamos la transacción
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- En caso de haber existido algún error en el TRY, 
    -- llegamos aquí y deshacemos todo el trabajo de la transacción
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    -- Terminamos regresando el error original.
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Recuerda que dejar transacciones abiertas puede detener por completo tu base de datos y afectar el sistema. Por ello es importante tomar todas las precauciones pertinentes y monitorear que no haya transacciones abiertas por demasiado tiempo.